# FILETIME implementation in C#

Tags: c#, c++, time

I am trying to convert some C++ project to C#. I am struggling now with a time class I encountered with C++. It has methods like:

```
const RsDateTime& RsDateTime::GetTime()
{
    FILETIME ft;
    ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
    ::FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&ft, &m_Time); // Why call to local time? What does it do?

    return *this;
}

FILETIME RsDateTime::GetUTCTimeAsFile() const
{
    FILETIME ft;
    ::LocalFileTimeToFileTime(&m_Time, &ft); // Why call to local time?
    return ft;
}

static unsigned __int64 GetAsUINT64(const FILETIME* ft)
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER li;
    li.LowPart = ft->dwLowDateTime;
    li.HighPart = ft->dwHighDateTime;
    return li.QuadPart;
}
```

Can someone please help me how to approach converting this to C#? Which methods do I need to use? Also what is the difference between `FileTime` and `LocalFileTime` as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

In Win32 (which this code seems to be), `FILETIME` is:

> A 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

Unless you're dependent on the 1601 epoch, in C#/.NET just use the `DateTime` type, which contains:

> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001.

My advice is to completely ditch/disregard the C++ code UNLESS you know the data it's returning is being used somewhere that depends on Win32 `FILETIME` specifically, if not, remove the code and use `System.DateTime`.

Comment: Dear Dai, I found out more precisely which parts of this class I need. Please find here: http://codepad.org/kG3OXToS. basically from there I need only first toDate function and GetAsPrepaidTime. Can you please answer me based on this information? How to achieve similar in C#? Like I said I will need those two functions. (Note: in st structure in first bullet is only assigned year, month, day, hour, minute and second values)

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` C# class now has a method `FromFileTime` which converts the 64bit FILETIME structure into a `DataTime` object. At that point, you can use all the `DateTime` methods and properties normally in c#.

```
Int64 exampleTime = 0x01cff7924ade4400L; 
DateTime dtModified = DateTime.FromFileTime(exampleTime);
```